# Passing React Navigation v5 authentication errors back to signup/in screen

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I am using React Navigation v5. I have an auth setup like their example in the docs. My problem is that I cannot work out how to pass error messages back to the component when there is a problem with signup/in.
The validation is done on the server and returned in the response object.
Currently the page just sits there with the loading spinner spinning while it waits for a response which it never receives.
Im going to try to cut down the amount of code I include here because it is basically a copy paste job from the docs

```
// Login.tsx

  const loginUser = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    signIn({ email, password });
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        label='Email'
        onChangeText={(text: string) => setEmail(text)}
        value={email}
      />
      <TextInput
        label='Password'
        onChangeText={(text: string) => setPassword(text)}
        value={password}
        secureTextEntry
      />
      {errorMessage && <Text>{errorMessage}</Text>}
      <Button mode='contained' disabled={showButton()} onPress={loginUser}>
        {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator color='white' /> : 'Submit'}
      </Button>
      <Button mode='outlined' onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SignUp')}>
        Go to sign up
      </Button>
    </View>
  );
```

```
// AuthStackNavigator.tsx

import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import SignupScreen from '../Screens/SignupScreen';
import LoginScreen from '../Screens/LoginScreen';

const AuthStack = createStackNavigator();
export const AuthStackScreen = () => {
  return (
    <AuthStack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerLeft: null }}>
      <AuthStack.Screen name='SignUp' component={SignupScreen} />
      <AuthStack.Screen name='SignIn' component={LoginScreen} />
    </AuthStack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default AuthStackScreen;
```

```
// Navigation.tsx

const authContext = useMemo(
    () => ({
      signIn: async ({ email, password }: SignInTypes) => {
        const userData = {
          email,
          password,
        };
        API.post
          .userLogin(userData)
          .then((result) => {
            if (
              result.data.status === 'fail' ||
              result.data.status === 'error'
            ) {
              setIsLoading(false);
              // I NEED TO DO SOMETHING HERE I THINK BUT ICANT WORK OUT WHAT I NEED TO DO
            }
            const accessToken = [
              'accessToken',
              result.data.data.tokens.accessToken.jwtToken,
            ];
            const refreshToken = [
              'refreshToken',
              result.data.data.tokens.refreshToken.token,
            ];
            addUser({
              id: result.data.data.user._id,
              email: result.data.data.user.email,
              profileName: result.data.data.user.profileName,
              balance: result.data.data.user.balance,
            });
            try {
              AsyncStorage.multiSet([accessToken, refreshToken]);
              setIsLoading(false);
              return dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_IN', token: accessToken[1] });
            } catch (e) {
              return console.log('ASYNC STORAGE ERROR', e);
            }
          })
          .catch((e) => {
            console.log('Sign in error', e);
          });
      }
    }),
    [],
  );

  const navigationOptions = () => {
    if (isLoading) {
      return <LoadingScreen />;
    }
    return !state.userToken ? (
      <AuthStackScreen />
    ) : (
      <AppStackScreen />
    );
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={authContext}>
      <NavigationContainer>{navigationOptions()}</NavigationContainer>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create two separate Stack navigators. AuthStack and MainStack. Like you have.
2. Conditionally render those stacks based on auth Status. Like you have.

```
// AuthStack containing the Login and SignUp screens.
export const AuthStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator headerMode="none">
      <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignInScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUpScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

```
// Main Stack that contains The rest of the screens and other navigation components.
export const MainStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={TabNavigator} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Ledger" component={LedgerScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="CustomerProfile" component={CustomerProfileScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
```

```
// App.tsx or which ever file you choose to wrap your Stacks in the Navigation container.

const App = (props) => {
  const isAuth = useSelector((state) => !!state.auth.token); // Comes from the redux store

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {isAuth && <MainStack />}
      {!isAuth && <AuthStack />}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App
```

Here, I'm using react-redux to get the isAuth variable that holds the token which verifies if the user is authenticated or not. But, you can use the useContext hook to achieve this as well.

Based on the user's login status the appropriate stacks are rendered.

You can now make your calls to API (the ones you are making in Navigation.tsx) from within the particular screen components itself inside the useEffect and useCallback hooks and get back the responses within the same component, which can include error messages.

Store those error messages in useState or useReducer hooks and display these errors to the user under the appropriate TextInputs or use an Alert Box to display them.

There is no need to pass props between the screen components and React Navigation 5 to get the error messages, if you make your api calls in the screen component itself.